# synaptic PPA repository error

Tags: 14.04, repository

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS-64 on a HP Pavilion dv7 laptop.  Yesterday I was adding a repository and when I did the "sudo apt-get update" I received this message:

```
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192
W: GPG error: http://mirror.symnds.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: http://mirror.symnds.com trusty-updates Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: http://mirror.symnds.com trusty-backports Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: http://mirror.symnds.com trusty-security Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
```

======================================

I have tried the "sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys ", and it does nothing to fix the issue.  I unticked all of my repositories, redid the update, same message.  I rebooted, still not fixing the issue, ame message.

When I did the "sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys " command this is what I got on saw on teh terminal:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5
[sudo] password for brwright: 
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.xYr7arweRj --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/aking1012-com-lenstoggle.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/alessandro-strada-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/alexx2000-doublecmd.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/amith-ubuntutools.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/antono-shelr.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/appgrid-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/apt-fast-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/arctica0316-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/askubuntu-tools-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/atareao-atareao.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/atareao-lenses.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/atareao-nautilus-extensions.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/banshee-team-banshee-daily.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/banshee-team-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/bhdouglass-indicator-remindor.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/bridge-daily.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/caffeine-developers-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cairo-dock-team-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cairo-dock-team-weekly.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/caldas-lopes-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cdekter-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/chris-lea-node_js-legacy.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/claudiocn-slm.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cooperjona-nitrotasks.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/costales-folder-color.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/costales-unity-webapps-telegram.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/danielrichter2007-grub-customizer.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/deja-dup-team-testing.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/diesch-testing.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/dlech-keepass2-plugins.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/dr3mro-personal.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ehoover-compholio.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/flozz-flozz.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/format-junkie-team-release.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/fossfreedom-indicator-sysmonitor.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/freyja-dev-unity-tweak-tool-daily.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/gencfsm-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/george-edison55-nitroshare.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/n-muench-burg.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/rednotebook-daily.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/webupd8team-y-ppa-manager.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5
gpg: keyblock resource `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/n-muench-burg.gpg': resource limit
gpg: keyblock resource `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/rednotebook-daily.gpg': resource limit
gpg: keyblock resource `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/webupd8team-y-ppa-manager.gpg': resource limit
gpg: requesting key 437D05B5 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 437D05B5: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" 26 new signatures
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:         new signatures: 26
```

==========================================================================

What do I do?  How did I fubar this?  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  The OS seems to be working just fine, no issues on reboot, or using the OS normally.  Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys  " command for all errors like:

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 16126D3A3E5C1192

Comment: I have tried this command, but as you can see in the blockquote  above, all I get is the same error message.

Comment: Well, after I sent you the above comment, I went to /etc/apt/.  I opened all of the folders (apt.conf.d, preferences.d, sources.list.d, trusted.gpg.d) In the 'trusted.gpg.d folder there were a whole bunch of leftover keys.  I deleted all of them.  Closed 'nautilus' and did a 'sudo apt-get update' command.  When it finished doing the update, there were no error messages.  Everything is now like it should be.  The problem is, I'm not sure what I did to cause this problem in the first place.  But, thank you for your suggestion.  I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this, but this problem can be closed out as 'solved'.  Thanks